# send value from hidden_field_tag in an ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a hidden_field_tag

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'render_date', @bikes.first.created_at %>
```

That translates to this in the DOM

```
<input id="render_date" name="render_date" type="hidden" value="2013-07-01 18:58:09 UTC">
```

How do I include the value of the input field in an ajax call so that it's accessible by the controller? (and how is it accessed)

```
<%= link_to 'update bikes', bikes_path, [something goes here], :remote=> true %>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
<%= link_to 'update bikes', bikes_path, 
          :variableName=>@bikes.first.created_at, :remote=> true %>
```

and remove the hidden field. In your controller access the variable with `params[:variableName]` keeping in mind the first time you go to the site there will be no value for `params[:variableName]` so you can't access is unless you use some sort of `if else` statement to make sure the value exists.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you can use jquery like so:

```
var someData = $('#render_date').val();
$.ajax({
  url: '/Controller/myAction',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { data: someData }
});
```

Then in your controller just make sure your action name takes in the data parameter.  I don't know ruby but here is a c# example:

```
public ActionResult myAction(string data) { 
  //function code 
}
```